# Should I copy code while making reference to another answer?

Tags: discussion

While posting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31125363/2291710) I was wondering: should I also copy the code which may interest OP from the answer I link?

Is it ok to just post an "see reference" answer?

Is not copying the code considered as self appropriation of someone else labor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From one side, the answer containing the link without the supplementing sources is considered link-only, from the other side, it's not valid to *copy sources from another answer on the same SE site which will essentially make your answer*.

If some information in answer from another question answers the new question you found, you should flag / close as duplicate, explaining why the question would be dupe **in comments** (which I would do in your case, and delete the answer at first).

Generally, having provided the full own answer, you can give link to another one, but not so as the most important information of your answer would be contained in a link to another post within the given SE site - a reference to another answer can be used to *support* yours.

Comment: I though to this, but what if the answer required some additional information? I could not mark it as duplicate, as the OP will only get part of the answer he was looking or.

Comment: @user In your case, the additional information is 99% of the whole info. :)

Comment: Guess what, I know it. I was talking in a more general way.

Comment: @user2737736 In this case the answer to the other question answers the question that the user has.  Given that, just mark the question as a duplicate.  As a rule, any time you feel that an answer that just points to another answer would sufficiently answer the question, either the questions are duplicates, or that link really wouldn't be a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write answer if you see another question's answer fit for the current question.

- comment the link(of that answer) to the post .
- If you think the question is duplicate flag it.
- Otherwise you can write your own answer referencing that answer.